# How can I loop through elements in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The code sample below works fine to produce a bunch of charts.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()

df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
# sklearn provides the iris species as integer values since this is required for classification
# here we're just adding a column with the species names to the dataframe for visualisation
df['species'] = np.array([iris.target_names[i] for i in iris.target])
sns.pairplot(df, hue='species')
```

[image]

The three lines of code below are somehow correctly handing all the data in the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
df['species'] = np.array([iris.target_names[i] for i in iris.target])
sns.pairplot(df, hue='species')


list(df)

['sepal length (cm)',
 'sepal width (cm)',
 'petal length (cm)',
 'petal width (cm)']
```

Now, I am loading my own data into a dataframe and trying to do the same, like this.

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\path_to_data\\test.csv')
df1 = df[df['officearea']!=0]
df1.shape
list(df1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1.data, columns=df1.feature_names)
list(df1)
```

At this point, using my data, I am getting the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'
```

On my data set, when I run this line:

```
list(df1)
```

I see this:

```
['index',
 'zone',
 'lot',
  etc., etc., etc.,
 'address',
 'sensor',
 'map']
```

Comment: `.data` here should be a column, the Iris datasets, had a `data` attribute , but yours don't. Also you only need to create the second df if you intend to make a subset, do you want to do this? Also you won't have a column called `feature_names`, this also something that is in the sample data and not in your csv

Comment: you can use `df1.values`  instead of `df1.data`

Comment: Weird.  I looked in the headers of the dataframe and didn't see anything named 'data' or 'feature_names'.  Ok, so I just tried this: df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1.values)
list(df1)  Now I have all numbers instead of column names.  I'm trying to iterate through a list and create a bunch of charts.  Maybe this is not the right approach.